# Bootloop in Xperia L when the bootloader is unlocked using sony's flashtool

Tags: boot-loop, flashtool, sony-xperia-l

I was trying to install AOSP rom for Xperia L provided by Sony. So i tried to unlock my device using Flash tool. I tried unlocking the device, it replied "failed" first and second time I tried, it ran some commands, said ok and requested for a Restart. And when i restart it displays SONY, XPERIA and gets caught in a loop displaying a image.

Is there something I missed before I unlock my device or there is a problem with the device?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally installed cyanogenmod 11 in my xperia L. Cyanogenmod added a developer release only now to their collection and it works smooth. Just followed the instruction presented in their website i was able to install CM11. I suppose the are problems with AOSP version of sony for xperia L.

Answer (score 0):

It always happens, you will have to reflash your stock firmware using pc companion.

Comment: This should not happen after unlocking the bootloader.

Comment: Yes we can flash the stock ROM but how to install cyanogen mod 11 in my phone. I already tried the XDA Dev links.